# Unable to upload Phonegap built APK to Google Play Console

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, phonegap-build, phonegap

I have just tried to upload a APK (as a beta release) generated from Phonegap Build to the Google Play Store.

Getting an error as follows:

```
Upload failed

You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play.
```

When I generated the apk from Phonegap the debuggable option is unmarked.

Any idea? Almost same application was uploaded last year and I didn't get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was adding an Android Key and to enable it. Without iOS or Android key the build won't work.

Answer (score 0):

First, generate your private key using the keytool command that comes with the JDK using the following command

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

For more information visit [Generating a private key](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/signing/android/)

Then create a file build.json like below and put it in your `<projectfolder>/buildConfig` folder

```
{
 "android": {
     "release": {
         "keystore": "my-release-key.keystore",
         "alias": "alias_name",
         "storePassword": "secretPassword",
         "password" : "secretPassword"
     }
 }
}
```

Keep your my-release-key.keystore file in `<projectfolder>/buildConfig` folder

Then execute the following command

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release --buildConfig ./buildConfig/build.json
```